# Shorten the php code by loop

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Happy new year everyone!Here is my codes.Is there any way to short the code by using a loop?In a loop,the first field display once and the corresponding subfield display 5 elements.
For example:
   first field: Web browser
   subfield elements:firefox,chrome,IE,opera,maxthon

```
<div class="row">
<?php 
$sort=get_field('category');
         echo "<div class='bor'></div>
               <h3 style='text-align:center'>".$sort[ 0 ]['fenlei']."
               <a id='browser'></a></h3>
               <div class='bor'></div>";   
$websites = get_field('classification');
$row_count = count($websites);
   for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++){
        include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/template.php');
       }



?>

        </div>  
      <!--end row1-->
 <div class="row">
<?php 
$sort=get_field('category');
         echo "<div class='bor'></div>
               <h3 style='text-align:center'>".$sort[ 1 ]['fenlei']."
               <a id='browser'></a></h3>
               <div class='bor'></div>";   
$websites = get_field('classification');
$row_count = count($websites);
   for ($i = 5; $i <= 9; $i++){
        include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/template.php');
       }



?>

        </div>  
      <!--end row2-->
 <div class="row">
<?php 
$sort=get_field('category');
         echo "<div class='bor'></div>
               <h3 style='text-align:center'>".$sort[ 2 ]['fenlei']."
               <a id='browser'></a></h3>
               <div class='bor'></div>";   
$websites = get_field('classification');
$row_count = count($websites);
   for ($i = 10; $i <= 14; $i++){
        include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/template.php');
       }



?>

        </div>  
      <!--end row3-->
```

the content of template.php

```
<div class="col-lg-2dot4">
      <div class="thumbnail" style="height: 360px;">
        <a href="<?php echo $websites[ $i ]['link']; ?>" title=<?php echo $websites[ $i ]['name']; ?> target="_blank">
          <img src="<?php echo $websites[ $i ]['icon']; ?>" width="194" height="97" />
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>
            <a href="<?php echo $websites[ $i ]['link']; ?>" title="Firefox" target="_blank"><?php echo $websites[ $i ]['name']; ?></a>
          </h3>
          <p><?php echo $websites[ $i ]['description'];; ?></p>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-inline text-center">
          <li style="list-style: none">Download:</li>
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $websites[ $i ]['download']; ?>" target="_blank">32Bit</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
<?php

function print_row($sort, $websites) {
  return function($limit_offset, $i) use($sort, $websites) {
    $start = $limit_offset[0];
    $end = $limit_offset[0] + $limit_offset[1];
    return "<div class='bor'></div>
            <h3 style='text-align:center'>"
      . $sort[$i]['fenlei']
      . "<a id='browser'></a></h3>
         <div class='bor'></div>"
      . implode('', array_map(range($start, $end), row_template($websites)));
    };
  }

  function row_template($websites) {
    return function($i) use($websites) {
      ob_start();
      include(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/template.php');
      return ob_get_contents();
    };
  }

  $sort = get_field('category');
  $websites = get_field('classification');
  $offsets = [[0, 4], [5, 4], [10, 4]];
  $results = array_map($offsets, print_row($sort, $websites));

  print implode('', $results);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not in a meaningful way, but a function is in order:

```
function echoCode($sortIndex,$start,$stop) {
    $sort=get_field('category');
    echo "<div class='bor'></div>
        <h3 style='text-align:center'>".$sort[$sortIndex]['fenlei']."
        <a id='browser'></a></h3>
        <div class='bor'></div>";   
    $websites = get_field('classification');
    $row_count = count($websites);
    for ($i = $start; $i <= $stop; $i++)
        include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/template.php');
}
```

then just call this twice with (0,0,4) and (1,5,9).

Comment: This was posted before the edit, and I understood you want to shorten the upper piece of code. If this is not it let me know.

Comment: Thanks for reply kabanus.I just want to shorten the upper code with a loop.

Comment: Like I said, it's not clear how a loop will help here. A function cuts your code in half - how do you suggest cutting more? Even if you insist, it would be a loop that runs twice and outputs that div in the middle by checking run number.

Comment: I have no idea at the moment.I will test your code again.